# Cannot use relative folder structure in NPM packages.json

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, npm, venv

Im using the example flask/react app from this github https://github.com/Faruqt/React-Flask

Problem is I have the `flask.exe` in `Project/venv/scripts` folder
and the repository is in `Project/React-Flask-master` fodler

I edited the Prackges.json to

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "temp": "cd ../",
    "start-backend": "cd backend && /../../venv/Scripts/flask run --no-debugger",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

But no matter what I try, I cannot use the relative folder structure.

I added a "temp" lien that is supposed to go one folder up, and even that doesnt work

```
(venv) C:\Code\Project\React-Flask-master>npm run temp

> flask_react@0.1.0 temp
> cd ../


(venv) C:\Code\Project\React-Flask-master>
```

And

```
(venv) C:\Code\aicode\AIbots\catgpt\React-Flask-master>npm run start-backend

> flask_react@0.1.0 start-backend
> cd backend && /../../venv/Scripts/flask run --no-debugger

The system cannot find the path specified.

(venv) C:\Code\aicode\AIbots\catgpt\React-Flask-master>
```

I tried using "../../" and "/../../"

Comment: If you're running inside your virtual environment already, just run `flask run --no-debugger`, don't try to run the script entry from its relative file location. All scripts in your venv can be called as normal commands irrespective of which dir you're in, for as as long as your venv is active (that's one of the reasons to _use_ a virtual environment =)